# How to align bootstrap form inputs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align some inputs in my modal. I am trying to set this up the proper way. I have looked and found many examples but they are not working with mine. I understand the bootstrap site says to use form-inline but I dont need my entire form setup like that. I just want the City/State/Zipcode inline with each other. Also you will see a checkbox on the top right corner. I have moved it to the right with a margin-left, but it messes up the responsiveness of it. What is the best way to do this?
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tspVWh9AXob3Lb9VAzyr?p=preview)

```
<div class="form-group clearfix inline">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">City</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
         <input style="width:200px" ng-model="customer.city" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
</div>

       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right" for="customerSt">State</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
           <select style="width:200px" ng-model="customer.st" class="form-control" ng-options="s.abbr as s.name for s in states">
             <option value="">-- Select a State --</option>
           </select>
        </div>

         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Zipcode</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input style="width:200px" ng-model="customer.zip" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
              </div>
         </div>
```

CheckBox

```
<div class="form-group clearfix" style="margin-left:520px">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Status</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input style="width:50px" type="checkbox" ng-model="job.status" value="" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to modify a little css and use nested columns.

[image]

This is an example of nesting columns in a form. You can use the same ideas to adjust your form.

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/kemumu/1/**

Regarding the checkbox that you pushed into place with margin. If it looks good at 900px but strange at under that width, then put  css in a min-width media query where it looks good and remove it outside the media query.

*Notes: `.form-group` puts some nice vertical spacing when a form is stacked (in smaller viewports) but it also acts like a .row (with its negative -left and -right margins), so this css when it's used on a column (as I have done) gets adjusted. Plus the gutter which is 30px is too big for a form.*

There's no need to put `.clearfix` on your `.form-group`s unless you've floated them for some reason.

**CSS EXAMPLE:**

```
.custom-form [class*="col-"].form-group {margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}

.custom-form .form-group [class*="col-"] .row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: .5%;
    padding-right: .5%;
}
.custom-form .form-group [class*="col-"] .row {
    margin-left: -.5%;
    margin-right: -.5%;
}
```

**HTML EXAMPLE:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal custom-form" role="form">

  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Card Holder's Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">

    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" placeholder="First Name" required>
     </div><!--nested col-sm-6-->

     <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" placeholder="Last Name" required>
     </div><!--nested col-sm-6-->

     </div><!-- /.form-group > .row -->
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-9 -->
   </div><!-- /.form-group -->

  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Credit Card Number:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" pattern="\d4" placeholder="1st four digits" required>
     </div>
     <!--nested col-sm-3-->

     <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" pattern="\d4" placeholder="2nd four digits" required>
     </div>
     <!--nested col-sm-3-->

     <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" pattern="\d4" placeholder="3rd four digits" required>
     </div>
     <!--nested col-sm-3-->

     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" pattern="\d4" placeholder="4th four digits" required>
     </div>
     <!--nested col-sm-3-->

     </div><!-- /.form-group > .row -->
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-9 -->
   </div><!-- /.form-group -->

  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Expiration Date:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
       <option>January</option>
       <option>...</option>
       <option>December</option>
      </select>
     </div>
     <!--nested col-sm-9-->

     <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
       <option>2013</option>
       <option>...</option>
       <option>2015</option>
      </select>
     </div>
     <!--nested col-sm-3-->

     </div><!-- /.form-group > .row -->
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-9 -->
   </div><!-- /.form-group -->

  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">CVV Code:</label>

   <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" pattern="\d3" placeholder="3 digits on back of card" required>
     </div><!--nested  col-sm-4-->


     </div><!-- /.form-group > .row -->
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-9 -->
   </div><!-- /.form-group -->

  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom">Cancel</button>
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 -->
   </div><!-- /.form-group -->

 </form><!-- /.form-horizontal -->

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

**

Answer (score 1):

If you want responsiveness in your site, then make/add different css and add them to different scree size.. for example..

```
<h2 class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Some text here</h2>
```

The above h2 heading will show on only tablet,s smart TV's, laptop's desktops etc....

```
 <h4 class="visible-xs">Some text here</h4>
```

When you see the same heading on small devices like smart phone's, or smaller, then it adjust it size according to the specified and only show on small devices....

**Note:**   Please Read the twitter bootstrap documentation about responsiveness  [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some custom css classes to do that. For example

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .input-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .input-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .input-inline select.form-control {
    width: auto;
  }
  .input-inline .radio,
  .input-inline .checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .input-inline .radio input[type="radio"],
  .input-inline .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
}
```

So no i do not add the form-inline class at my form. When i need an inline input I write the following:

```
<div class="form-group input-inline">
  <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control">
<div>
```

I might have missed copying something from my code but this is the general idea. You just need to copy from bootstrap the .form-inline values and replace it with .input-inline.

Comment: I updated the plunkr. I added the css and the input-inline but not changing. can you please take a look